# is there any way to communicate two vnets without using peering concept

Tags: azure, networking, convnetsharp

i am stuck here kindly help

1.i have created 3 vnets i.e Vnet1,Vnet2, Vnet3

i have established peering between vnet1-vnet2 and vnet2-vnet3 but i want to make a connection between vnet1 -vnet3 without using peering method is there any way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vnet-to-vNet VPN:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal
Why you don't want to use peering? It's pretty simple and works pretty good.